# ionic 2 sqlite plugin_not_installed

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, typescript, ionic2

pls help me i cant solve my problem on ionic 2 sqlite. on the first run of my app i have successfully created the table "players", and i can also insert and fetch on this table. but when i try to exit and re-open my app it prompts me "plugin_not_installed".

i am following the new documentation of [ionic frame work](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/) . i observe on this documentation it doesn't have db.openDatabase() function which some tutorials always mention.

```
   import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
export class Players {
    name:string;    //ngmodel from html
    players:new Array<Object>(); //used to list all players
constructor(private sqlite: SQLite,public alertCtrl: AlertController) { 
this.initializeDatabase(); //create table if not exists

}
ionViewDidLoad(){
        this.fetch();
}
initializeDatabase(){
    this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('create table if not exists(playerId integer primary key,fullname varchar(50));', {})
      .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => this.showAlert( JSON.stringify(e)));
  })
  .catch(e => this.showAlert( JSON.stringify(e)));
}
fetch(){
        let sql="select fullname from players";
        this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql(sql, {})
      .then((data) => {
          this.players=[];
          for(let index=0;index,data.rows.length;index++){
              this.players.push({fullname:data.rows.item(index).fullname});
          }
      })
      .catch(e => this.showAlert( JSON.stringify(e)));
  })
  .catch(e => this.showAlert( JSON.stringify(e)));
}
create(){
    let name=this.name;
        let sql="INSERT INTO players (playerId,fullname) values (?,?)";
        this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql(sql, [null,name])
      .then(() => console.log('successfully created'))
      .catch(e => this.showAlert( JSON.stringify(e)));
  })
  .catch(e => this.showAlert( JSON.stringify(e)));
}
  showAlert(msg:string) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Info',
      subTitle:msg,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: additionally when i try to exit and re-open my app several times sometimes this error don't comes up.

Comment: can you add the code? [mcve]

Comment: hi sir @suraj thank you for your reply, how can i add the code? the comment box said it was too long

Comment: use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43907767/edit) button..and `{}` button inside for adding code snippet

Comment: thanks , i already posted my code

Comment: when you call cordova plugins call within `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`

Comment: thank you sir @suraj i already did that. the results are the same.

Comment: i already added a loadingController to postpone somehow between the creation of tables and fetching but its the same.

Comment: try reinstalling the plugin `ionic plugin add <name> --save`

Comment: hi sir @suraj , i already tried my luck on re moving and re-installing the sqlite plugin. actually its my 2nd dummy project created just to test this error. it's just keeping me wonder why sometimes it work and sometimes prompts my "plugin not installed" when i tried to exit and open my app.

Comment: I dont see any other issue with the code.. could be ionic-native related?

Comment: actually posting this problem to stackoverflow is my last resort. i already tried several methods to overcome this.i cant anymore continue my project because of this error im losing hope

Comment: maybe raise an issue in their github? is it device specific?

Comment: hi @suraj, yes my code works perfectly as it can insert and fetch my data. its just so annoying when i try to re open my app again i cant anymore view my list of players because it said "plugin_not_installed". im very thankful for your cooperation but im so sad i cant continue my work

Comment: hi sir @suraj, i didnt try this to other phones because i have only 1 smart android phone. maybe i will try to other devices. uhmmm, did you notice sir the documentation of ionic-framework im just wandering why it doesnt have db.openDatabase() function.

Comment: Encounteredd an exact same error how did you solve it?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270455/813951

Answer (score -1):

install the SQLite plugin using the below command :

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save
>
> npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite

Import the SQLite class to the app.module.ts file

> import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
>
> providers: [**SQLite**, ...

and build in your device

Comment: as lankean sad, the first time the app run and created the tables, so the plugin are installed...